Combining these two batch files
I currently have two batch files that work on their own.
This batch file checks if the time is after 8am and before 5:30pm, as well as checking that the day is not Saturday or Sunday (Mon-Friday only):
@echo off    
    set "now=%time: =0%"

    set "task=off"
    if "%now%" geq "08:00:00,00" if "%now%" lss "17:30:00,00" if not %DATE:~0,1%==S ( set "task=on" )

    call :task_%task%

    endlocal
    exit /b

:task_on
    call timeout /t 50 && Rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation

:task_off
    exit

I also have this code, that shows that the ping was successful, or if it isn't it logs the user out:
@echo off
ping 192.168.1.123 -n 1 | find "Reply" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 (
    echo Ping Sucessfull
) else (
    call Rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
) 

I've tried to combine them together and I can't seem to get it to work. I want to get rid of "Ping Successful" and add the first code in:
@echo off  
ping 192.168.1.123 -n 1 | find "Reply" > nul
if not errorlevel 1 ( 
    set "now=%time: =0%"

    set "task=off"
    if "%now%" geq "08:00:00,00" if "%now%" lss "17:30:00,00" if not %DATE:~0,1%==S ( set "task=on" )

    call :task_%task%

    endlocal
    exit /b

:task_on
    call timeout /t 50 && Rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation

:task_off
    exit

) else (
    call Rundll32.exe user32.dll,LockWorkStation
) 

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? I'm new to batch files, and I think it could be my indents.

As well as the duplicate I've linked. You also cannot have labels within a parenthesized code block, and call is for batch files, not exe files like timeout.exe and Rundll32.exe; (please remove it from those).

@Compo Sorry I am new to this so I don't really understand how I can fix it.. Any tips?
